# Pybind11 - Failing in Travis / Virtualenv

Tags: travis-ci, pyenv, pybind11

My Pybind project seems to be compiling fine on my system, but when I perform unit testing on travis, it throws the following error:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /opt/pyenv/shims/python3.7 (found version "1.4") 
CMake Error at 3rdparty/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:95 (message):
  Python config failure:
  pyenv: python3.7: command not found

  The `python3.7' command exists in these Python versions:
    3.7
    3.7.1
```

This seems to be something to do with virtualenv which I have never used. I currently have no idea how to solve this issue, and given that its in a travis instance, i'm not sure how to recreate it on my system so I may fix it

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in your case is that the wrong Python version is being used by travis.

For example, if you are using Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) in your .travis.yml configuration, you have to specify the version you want for Python when you call CMAKE.

For example, something like

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(python-config --prefix)/bin/python3.5 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python-config --prefix)/lib/libpython3.5m.so -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python-config --prefix)/include/python3.5m ..
```

Other versions of Ubuntu will have different versions of Python.

References:

https://github.com/vgc/vgc/issues/42

https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/99#issuecomment-207782425

Answer (score 0):

just to add to Murilo's answer, you could use Miniconda as a workaround as well, and configure CMAKE in a similar way by just changing the paths to the ones in your Miniconda env. I ran into issues when using multiple jobs for different Ubuntu distributions (xenial and bionic), which had somewhat different paths to the python libraries and headers.

- Here there's a link to a [travis with miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/use-conda-with-travis-ci.html) snippet which you could use to setup miniconda along a travis build.
- You can then use the following CMAKE configuration in your travis.yml file (note that the environment with name **travis_env** was created with **python=3.6**):

```
script:
  # ... 
  - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$HOME/miniconda/envs/travis_env/bin/python3.6 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$HOME/miniconda/envs/travis_env/lib/libpython3.6m.so -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$HOME/miniconda/envs/travis_env/include/python3.6m ..
  # ...
```